# Handling radio click in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, kendo-ui

I am new with kendo UI and javascript.

Actually, I am using Kendo UI in my new phonegap application. I want to show/hide particular control on radio change event. Below is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                          $('.block1').hide();
                          $('#thankYouMsgChild').hide();
                          $('#yesResultChild').hide();
                          $('#noMultiResponse').hide();
                          $('#yesMultiResponse').hide();
                          $('#surveyPageChild').hide();
                          $('#yesResponseCnt').hide();
                          $('#yesPassword').hide();
                          $('#yesIPBlocking').hide();
                          $('#addCutOffTime').hide();
                          });


        $("input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
                                    alert("Change Call");
                                    if(this.id=="eliminatePage" || this.id=="eliminateMsg"){
                                        $('.block1').hide();
                                        $("#"+this.value+"").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesThanks"){
                                        $("#thankYouMsgChild").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noThanks"){
                                        $("#thankYouMsgChild").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesResult"){
                                        $("#yesResultChild").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noResult"){
                                        $("#yesResultChild").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesMultiResp"){
                                        $("#noMultiResponse").hide();
                                        $("#yesMultiResponse").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noMultiResp"){
                                        $("#noMultiResponse").show();
                                        $("#yesMultiResponse").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="surveyPage"){
                                        $("#surveyPageChild").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesResponse"){
                                        $("#yesResponseCnt").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noResponse"){
                                        $("#yesResponseCnt").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesPwd"){
                                        $("#yesPassword").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noPwd"){
                                        $("#yesPassword").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesIP"){
                                        $("#yesIPBlocking").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noIP"){
                                        $("#yesIPBlocking").hide();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="yesTime"){
                                    $("#addCutOffTime").show();
                                    }
                                    else if(this.id=="noTime"){
                                    $("#addCutOffTime").hide();
                                    }
                                    });
```

But radio change event is not called. So please anybody can look over this and let me know what's the actual problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: lastly, you should call just `else` not `else if`

Comment: I did that also. But I think that's not real cause of not executing this method.

Comment: do you mean the `alert("Change Call");` is not firing as well?

Comment: yes. Control doesn't reach to that function

Answer (score 0):

I think problem not in Kendo UI and not in JavaScript code, guess need check html markup of your page.
I made test page,http://jsfiddle.net/dnisterlark/VqHEV/, all works perfect.

```
[ignore this - just including a code block so stackoverflow will
let me post the above JSFiddle link.  Yeah, seriously.]
```